# SwiftUI - Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[SignUpViewModel.ErrorMessage]'

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm fetching an array of error messages via API during a failed signup attempt to show a user during a failed signup event.  I'm then trying to assign that array of error messages to a Published variable in my ViewModel so I can update my View.

I'm getting an error when I try to set this array to match a struct and a published variable.  I'm confused as to the error as both are apparently arrays.

I know I'm getting an array as when I print the fullMessages array I get: ["Email has already been taken"].  I'd like to keep this as an array as some scenarios will return two error messages or more.

Here's my ViewModel for this action:

```
import Foundation

class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {


@Published var email: String = ""
@Published var companyName: String = ""
@Published var username: String = ""
@Published var firstName: String = ""
@Published var lastName: String = ""
@Published var password: String = ""
@Published var passwordConfirmation: String = ""
@Published var phoneNumber: String = ""
@Published var isConsumer: Bool = true
@Published var isChecked: Bool = false
@Published var showSignUpErrors: Bool = false
@Published var emailIsInvalid: Bool = false
@Published var companyNameisInvalid: Bool = true
@Published var phoneNumberisInvalid: Bool = false
@Published var passwordLengthError: Bool = false
@Published var passwordConfirmationError: Bool = false
@Published var passwordMatchError: Bool = false
@Published var formIsInvalid: Bool = true
@Published var showSignUpView: Bool = false

@Published var errorObjects: BadSignUpResponse = BadSignUpResponse.init(status: "Here",
                                                                        data: DataClass.init(
                                                                            id: 0,
                                                                            email: "",
                                                                            createdAt: "",
                                                                            updatedAt: "",
                                                                            firstName: "",
                                                                            lastName: "",
                                                                            streetAddress1: "",
                                                                            streetAddress2: "",
                                                                            city: "", state: "", country: "",
                                                                            username: "", companyName: "",
                                                                            zipCode: "", phoneNumber: "",
                                                                            stripeCustID: "",
                                                                            availableCredits: 0,
                                                                            provider: "", uid: "",
                                                                            allowPasswordChange: false, removeMyAccount: false
                                                                        ),
                                                                        errors: Errors.init(
                                                                            email: [], username: [],
                                                                            full_messages: ["Here is the first message",
                                                                            "here is the second message"]
                                                                        ))

@Published var errorMessages: [ErrorMessage] = []

struct ErrorMessage: Codable {
    let error: String
}



func signUp() {
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    SignUpService().signUp(email: email.lowercased(), username: username, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, password: password, passwordConfirmation: passwordConfirmation, category: category) { result in
        switch result {
        case.success(let sessionToken):
                defaults.set(sessionToken.accessToken, forKey: "access-token")
                defaults.set(sessionToken.client, forKey: "client")
                defaults.set(self.email.lowercased(), forKey: "userEmail")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    LoginViewModel().isAuthenticated = true
                    LoginViewModel().authenticationDidFail = false
                    LoginViewModel().loginButtonClicked = false
                    LoginViewModel().showLogin = false
                    self.showSignUpView = false
                    print("Great success!")
                    
                }
            case.failure(let errorResponse):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    LoginViewModel().authenticationDidFail = true
                    LoginViewModel().isAuthenticated = false
                    LoginViewModel().loginButtonClicked = false
                    LoginViewModel().showLogin = false
                    self.showSignUpErrors = true
                    self.showSignUpView = true
                    self.errorObjects = errorResponse

                    guard let fullMessages = errorResponse.errors.full_messages else {
                        return
                    }
                    print(fullMessages)
                    **** self.errorMessages = fullMessages *****
                }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: In order to help you, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Ali What am I missing from the write-up above?  I provided the error in the subject along with all of the relevant code that executes against it.

Comment: Swift is already telling you the issue. You are trying to assign a variable of type [String] to [SignUpViewModel.ErrorMessage]. This is clearly not working. If you would read the link I provided you, you would know what you are missing. I cannot reproduce your error, since the code you provide is not even compilable, because it is just a cut-out with various classes missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift is telling you the exact problem. You are trying to assign a variable of type [String] to [SignUpViewModel.ErrorMessage]

Here is working code showing you a possible solution. Since you only have a list of strings, I chose to use [Array.map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map)

```
import Foundation

var errorMessages: [ErrorMessage] = []

let fullMessages = ["Error response"]

struct ErrorMessage: Codable {
    let error: String
}

// This is not working: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[ErrorMessage]'
//errorMessages = fullMessages

// Instead just map it to your custom struct
errorMessages = fullMessages.map { ErrorMessage(error: $0)}
print(errorMessages)
```

You can also directly map from a json response using the Codable protocol:

```
let json = """
   [
    {"error": "Error A"},
    {"error": "Error B"}
   ]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decoded = try! decoder.decode([ErrorMessage].self, from: json)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure why I can't just assign an array to an array though.  Good to know mapping is an option.

Comment: Its not about the array, its about *ErrorMessage*. In a type save language you cannot assign variables of different types `( x: ErrorMessage != x: String)`